# EF Core .NET API is not able to connect to SQL Server container in Docker compose and errors out

Tags: sql-server, docker, entity-framework, docker-compose

I have a project where different microservices are created to learn microservices, now I want to host them into the docker using Docker compose as I myself need that in my own project soon so learning, now I am not able to connect to the API to the SQL server inside the Docker, so I am trying with just one API (having EF Core), a front end and a SQL Server Docker container, now I have written Docker compose as below.

When I just run SQL Server inside docker and use Docker profile in Visual Studio and run API, it connects to that SQL Server without any issue.

*More info about API:* it is creating the DB and table and inserting some dummy data (seeding) in the table using EF core

Now the code:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  mango.web:     <== this is just web ui, please ignore this, it is working
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mangoweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Mango.Web/Dockerfile
  mango.product:          <== this is the point of failure, not able to connect, api project
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mangoproduct
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Mango.Services.ProductAPI/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - mango.mssql
  mango.mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: sqlservermango
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Password@1234
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1432:1433"
```

The API code, will put just `Program.cs` code here, it is using EF core, let me know if you need more code I can add later

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        op => op.EnableRetryOnFailure());   // <=== Many answer said add this, but did not help
});
IMapper mapper = MappingConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.AddSecurityDefinition(name: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, securityScheme: new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Description = "Enter the Bearer Authorization string as following: `Bearer Generated-JWT-Token`",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference= new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                }
            }, new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
builder.AddAppAuthetication();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Cart API");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    }
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();
ApplyMigration();
app.Run();


void ApplyMigration()
{
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var _db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        if (_db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)  //<== this line fails
        {
            _db.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

The error (from container logs) that I am getting when I am running these in Docker compose environment

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
> 2023-08-09 16:58:45 --->Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'MangoProductAPI' on server 'mangomicroservice' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later

The connection string

> "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost,1432;Database=MangoOrder;User id=sa;password=Password@1234;TrustServerCertificate=True;"

Now here are the things that I tried after reading asnwers from various forums (since last 2 days)

1. Changed the connection string to `server=mango.mssql;Database=MangoOrder;User id=sa;password=Password@1234;TrustServerCertificate=True;`
2. Changed it to `server=mangomicroservice;Database=MangoProductAPI;User id=sa;password=Password@1234;TrustServerCertificate=True;` after looking at the error
3. Changed the connection string to `server=localhost,1432;Initial Catalog=MangoOrder;User id=sa;password=Password@1234;TrustServerCertificate=True;`
4. Added `EnableRetryOnFailure()` in `program.cs` with timeout,retry after seconds
5. Added `restart policy` (restart after 30 seconds) on product API after the SQL server container starts in `docker-compose.yml`
6. As I said above ran just the SQL Server inside Docker compose and ran API project from docker profile from Visual Studio after adding the dev container in same `docker network` (as API gave me error that it is not able to find the SQL Server on network) as the SQL Server is, **Please note this is working** I just wanted to test if the API is really able to connect to the SQL Server and wanted to debug the problem.

Now I am really out of options and answers on the forum, even tried everything that ChatGPT said but nothing helped.

Request your help.

Comment: At what point do you create the `MangoOrder` database inside the Docker container? It needs to exist before a successful connection can be made with a connection string can referencing `Initial Catalog=MangoOrder;`. If you consult the [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) you can see how to do this via the link, [using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize).

Comment: Apologies @AlwaysLearning but could not understand the question. when I run it using the debg mode it creates when I run it and then `DbCContext.OnModelCreating` fills the data. the link that you have given is good when we do not have EFCore if I understand it correctly.

Comment: it seems the connection string is different? ``Database 'MangoProductAPI' on server 'mangomicroservice' is not currently available``

Comment: Another issue is likely the use of `server=localhost,1432;` for two reasons: 1) each Docker container is its own little Linux VM, from a networking perspective `localhost` refers to itself, and 2) port 1432 is only the port published on the Docker host, containers will be connecting amongst each other on their exposed ports (i.e.: 1433). If you open a Docker terminal to `mango.product` and from there `ping mango.mssql` and `ping sqlservermango` which one responds? (I expect it will be the latter.) That is the host name you'll need to use the connection string in `mango.product`.

Comment: @sa-es-ir I tried that but still not working, I saw that in error and tried to do that but did not work. @AlwaysLearning the `mango.product` is not staying up for long time so can't do the ping. Moreover I have tried to put the `sqlservermango` ,`mango.mssql` and `localhost` in the `server` but it did not work either. that i what I am struggling with, there is something really small my intution says that but not able find what, so i need help from your help.